# Is it possible to use cascaded 1 bit magnitude comparators to create an n bit magnitude comparator?

Tags: digital-logic

I know it is possible to use 4 bit comparators to create N bit comparators as shown in this Data Sheet

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54s85.pdf

but is it possible to do it with 1 bit comparators?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. First compare the Most Significant Bits of both numbers using a 1-bit comparator, if they are equal you need to compare the next bit, else you can conclude which number is greater. The process continues, that is if the bits are equal, compare the next 2 bits of the 2 numbers.

Comment: It's a good start BUT you really need to explain it in more detail. A basic circuit diagram would be very useful. Use Ctrl-M in editor to open inbuilt schematic editor.